# ¿Por qué me surge este error a la hora de intentar descargar datos de Trading View?

Tags: python

A la hora de escribir el código, me sale un error el cual me dice UnboundLocalError: local variable 'driver' referenced before assignment. ¿Alguien sabría cómo solucionarlo?
Adjunto imagen del código y del error.

```
from selenium import webdriver

from tvDatafeed import TvDatafeed, Interval

import datetime

import logging

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)

tv=TvDatafeed(auto_login=False)
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: El código y los errores van como texto. Puedes editar tu pregunta para agregarlos.

Comment: ¿Ahora se entiende mejor?

Comment: Ligeramente, pero la traza está incompleta

Comment: El código está escrito en Jupyter Notebook